# PHP, array - mixed order, steam api returns different order

Tags: php, steam, steam-web-api

how I can sort this by number, 0 - 1+ not by first letter?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$players = array();             

$playerIds = [
    '76561197972192473',
    '76561198972352439',
    '76561198087304080',
    '76561198799985528',
    '76561198338485290'
];

$url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=294CFDFSFCWE5EG5FE4&steamids=".implode(',', $playerIds);
$json_object= file_get_contents($url);
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);

foreach ($json_decoded->response->players as $key=>$player) {

    $players[] = [
        'name' => $player->personaname,
        'profileurl' => $player->profileurl,
        'avatarfull' => $player->avatarfull,
        'personastate' => $player->personastate
    ];
} 

usort($players, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['name'] === $b['name']) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a['name'] < $b['name']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

When I remove usort, steam api will return ids everytime in different order, so can you help me how I can make it starts with 0 from playerIds.

Comment: Is there a `$player->playerid` ???  What is the name of the id returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `steamid` as the index and then sort it on keys:

```
foreach ($json_decoded->response->players as $key=>$player) {
    $players[$player->steamid] = [
        'name' => $player->personaname,
        'profileurl' => $player->profileurl,
        'avatarfull' => $player->avatarfull,
        'personastate' => $player->personastate
    ];
}
ksort($players);
```

Alternately, you could do it the way you're doing it but add the `steamid` to the `$players` array:

```
$players[] = [
    'id' => $player->steamid,
    'name' => $player->personaname,
    'profileurl' => $player->profileurl,
    'avatarfull' => $player->avatarfull,
    'personastate' => $player->personastate
];
```

Then sort on the `id`:

```
array_multisort(array_column($players, 'id'), SORT_DESC, $players);
```

There is maybe a parameter to be passed to the API that will return them sorted the way you want, not sure.